# Windows registry diff

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm trying to troubleshoot a commercial Windows 10 software program that will no longer load, even after uninstalling and reinstalling. The manufacturer guesstimates that something is not getting properly removed from the Windows registry during the uninstallation process, and thus remains "broken" after reinstalling, but they are unsure what to look for.

I have a clean machine, so I'm wondering if this is possible: Get a dump of the Windows registry before the initial install, then get a dump of the Windows registry after installing, and perform some kind of diff on them to see what was actually changed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say it "no longer loads" what does that mean exactly?  Does the application start then almost instantly crash?  Does the application never even attempt to load, which would indicate, a require DLL does not exist on the machine.  We need more details.  Be as specific as possible.  What are the prerequisite requirements for this application?

Comment: Did they give you a steer as to which section of the registry to look in? If you compare the entire registry for 2 machines, you'll be there for a very long time. I would take a snapshot of the registry on the clean machine, install the commercial software, take another snapshot and compare those. Comparing 2 machines would be unnecessary. You can open the 2 `.reg` file in Notepad++, and run a compare.

Comment: The program is "starting" in some sense of the word. I see the program in the task manager, but it fails to load the GUI, and after a couple of min I get an error message from the tool "Launcher time out", then it closes. The tool produces an empty log file (lol)

Comment: @spikey_richie I was hoping there was some way to dump the registry in some form of text file, that way I can use a text diff tool to compare. I also would not want to manually step through the entire registry.

Comment: You can export reg keys to `.txt`, but the whole registry would be huge. Can the 3rd party give you an idea of where its keys are going? I would assume it's `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`, but you should ask.

Comment: I've asked, but they weren't able to provide it. My impression is that their software guru has left the company.

Comment: I would start by exporting `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` and `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` to a `.reg` or `.txt` file, install their software, and then export those 2 keys again. Compare the before and after for both, and you should see the differences being their software keys. Notepad++ will let you compare `.reg` files.

Comment: @spikey_richie I feel like I need to get the entire registry because I only have 1 chance on the clean machine: Once the software is installed, if their theory is true, then the registry change will be persistent, and I will no longer be able to get a meaningful diff on the other registry directories.

Comment: @SittinHawk See my answer for a number of different options. The first one does what you ask (compare registry snapshots)

Comment: @SittinHawk Use a VM as the clean machine and make a snapshot of the VM before installing. You can roll back to the snapshot as many time as you like.

Comment: "Launcher time out" actually sounds like a licensing server communication failure. Wondering if the registry is a red herring

Comment: @Yorik anything's possible I suppose. For this particular program, it normal lets you open and run the app even without a license, then once you click "build", that's when it checks for a license. Also, I use a USB dongle license, in which I've confirmed that the computer is communicating properly with it (I can read the correct "FlexID").

Comment: I see a few recent whisperings of HASP driver incompatability with respect to FlexLM dongles and certain win10 release numbers. If you haven't already, might also keep an eye out for that as a source of issues.

Comment: I suspect your approach will lead nowhere. I also think technical support made something up. 1. Start the program from a command prompt. Does it say anything. 2. Download WinDbg and start the program from within WinDbg. For a brief primer see https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html.

Comment: @user1644677 It says nothing when starting from the command prompt. I will try the WinDbg approach. For my own education, why do you suspect that it's not the registry approach?

Comment: If the program is a GUI program eg non console program are you sure the window isn't off screen. Does it appear on the taskbar. If it is the registry (and it rarely is) an easier way to check is run the program with Process Monitor. WinDbg monitors what programs are doing internally. Process Monitor looks at what programs are reading/writing (files and registry).

Comment: Technical support are making stuff up. You are wasting you time as a result.

Comment: Here is the link to MS's web site for Process Monitor. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I get the diff of the registry before and after installing software?

There are a couple of options.

1. [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) from [Nisoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/)

> RegistryChangesView is a tool for Windows that allows you to take a snapshot of Windows Registry and later compare it with another Registry snapshots, with the current Registry or with Registry files stored in a shadow copy created by Windows.
>
> When comparing 2 Registry snapshots, you can see the exact changes made in the Registry between the 2 snapshots, and optionally export the Registry changes into a standard .reg file of RegEdit.

Source [RegistryChangesView - Compare snapshots of Windows Registry](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html)

Use this to make before and after snapshots of the registry to see what the installation program has changed.

2. RegFromApp from [Nisoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/)

> `RegFromApp` monitors the Registry changes made by the application that you selected, and creates a standard `RegEdit` registration file (.reg) that contains all the Registry changes made by the application. You can use the generated .reg file to import these changes with `RegEdit` when it's needed.

Source: [RegFromApp - Generate RegEdit .reg file from Registry changes made by application](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html)

Use this to monitor the register changes made by the installation program

3. [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from Microsoft

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, `Filemon` and `Regmon`, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such as session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

Source: [Process Monitor - Windows Sysinternals | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Use this to monitor registry changes in real time.

As pointed out by [Yorik](https://superuser.com/users/426758/yorik) in a comment:

> Process monitor can also help identify what the program is doing prior to entering the "not loaded state" (i.e. crashing/exiting), since it does more than just track registry activity

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Nirsoft in any way, I am just an end user of their software.</sup>

Comment: Process monitor can also help identify what the program is doing prior to entering the "not loaded state" (i.e. crashing/exiting), since it does more than just track registry activity

Comment: @Yorik Good point. Added to answer